# Building GLM Model with dependent variable as a proportion for 4 categories using R software

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, multinomial-distribution

I am trying to develop a Generalized Linear Model (GLM) in which the dependent data is a
proportion data with 4 categories. I want to develop this model as an
alternative method to Multinomial Logit Model for comparison of
results. Here is the sample data.

```
Category SharesY x1 x2
1 0.80 7480 628
2 0.03 5178 1011
3 0.16 6711 1391
4 0.01 4177 1845
1 0.79 7562 628
2 0.05 5260 1011
3 0.15 6779 1391
4 0.01 5048 1693
...
```

By running this as a GLM model with family as binomial, and link
function as logit I am getting a warning message:

```
"In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!".
```

Also, the coefficients I am getting are not comparable to that of the MNL model.

I am very new to R, and not sure whether it is even possible to run
GLM model using proportion data but I read it somewhere and hence
tried it.

Also, is it required to do any transformation on the dependent variable before running the GLM?

Any ideas/ thoughts/ alternate ways to run GLM using proportion data
then please let me know.

Comment: Do you have the number of trials the proportions are based on? If so, this sounds like data for a multinomial model.

Comment: The data which I am trying to model is for the freight corridor choice, where I have the quantity of freight (in tons) available for each of the corridor for a given Origin-destination pair. I have calculated the proportions using the freight transferred using each of the corridor. Yes, this data is best modeled as a multinomial logit, and there is already a multinomial logit being developed. What I am looking for is to develop an alternate model to compare the results with that of MNL model. Is it possible to model this data using GLM or any other method? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: The [mlogit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/index.html) package fits multinomial logit models. Just to be sure, are you confident that your dependent variable is nominal, as opposed to ordinal?

Comment: @jthetzel: The data I have is for corridor choice. In the above example I have numbered them from 1 to 4 but they actually represent four different routes say A,B,C,D and these are not ranked in any order. Therefore, yes the dependent variable is nominal.